# Negative \contentsmargin changes page number alignment in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am using `\titletoc` to modify a table of contents. The problem is that the command `\contentsmargin{-1.5em}` seems to change the alignment of the page numbers (from right to left).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{-0.5em}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}}
{}
{}
{
\titlerule*[1pc]{}
\contentspage
}

\titlecontents{subsection}[1em]
{\addvspace{0pt}}
{}
{}   % \textit · •
{\titlerule*[1pc]{}
\contentspage
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\contentsmargin` should not be negative. It is the width of the box in which the page number is typeset. Typesetting in a negative-width box apparently doesn't give the proper results. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to reduce the margin (which it somewhat does, but with this undesired side effect) in a two-column table of contents.

Comment: Your example doesn't have a two-column table of contents. But if you just want to change margins, this can be done easily with `\usepackage{changepage}` and the `adjustwidth` environment.